# Ember cli Managing dependencies for custom folders

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli, broccolijs

I have an ember app, and a folder with a file `playGame/game.js`. This file includes game logic, and I want to import it for asset compilation.

If this file is under `app/playGame/game.js` and my Brocfile is like this:

`app.import('app/playGame/game.js')`

this gives the error, path or pattern `app/playGame/game.js` didn't match any files..

but if I put the file under `bower_components/playGame/game.js` and my Brocfile:

`app.import('bower_components/playGame/game.js')`, this compiles successfully.

What is the problem and solution here?

Answer (score 2):

There are two parts to this:

1. Where should I put my file to import it as an asset?
2. Why isn't putting it in my `app`-folder working?

The way to do what you want is to create a folder called `vendor` in your root, put the file somewhere in there, and then import it in your `Brocfile.js` like so:

```
app.import('vendor/playGame/game.js');
```

This is [documented on ember-cli.com](http://www.ember-cli.com/#folder-layout), although somewhat hidden.

You could also put it in `bower_components`, but that folder is for things installed with `bower`, and could theoretically be deleted (in fact, this is a common recommendation to various issues). Things in `bower_components` is also not checked in to version control by default, which you probably want to do in this case.

This should solve your issue.

---

Now, why doesn't it work to put it in `/app`?

`app` is a special folder. From the documentation:

> Contains your Ember application’s code. Javascript files in this
>   folder are compiled through the ES6 module transpiler and concatenated
>   into a file called `app.js`.

This is what makes it possible for you to `import` stuff from within your app. The folders in `app` is available directly under your `<appname>` namespace, along with some other files and folders like `config/environment`.

Example:

```
import myWidget from 'my-app/widgets/my-widget';`
```

The referenced file is `/app/widgets/my-widget.js`.

The `ember-cli` website has [some more resources for how to use modules](http://www.ember-cli.com/#using-modules). Read those if this doesn't make any sense.

To sum up:

1. You could put your file in `app`, but that would make it part of your transpiled package, and you'd have to use it that way internally with an `export` and everything else that comes with it. It would end up as part of `<appname>.js`
2. You could put your file in `vendor` and import it in your `Brocfile.js` as explained above. It would be part of `vendor.js` and load before your app code.